# JSON Variables into jquery/HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to reference some JSON variables on page load. Based on a value being true/false, append a class to an html element.

Can't getting this to work, would appreciate some help - being new to jquery and all.

```
// html
<form id="add_form">
<script type="application/json" data-type="product"
{"product_options": [
{"sku": "ABC123", "price": "$10", "in_stock": true, "can_order": true, "option1": "Small"},
{"sku": "DEF456", "price": "$20", "in_stock": false, "can_order": false, "option1": "Medium"}], "id": 31, "name": "Some Shirt style"}
</script>...</form>
```

I'd like to iterate through the elements of the .size_options class and add a class to the li element based on the "in_stock" value in the JSON; i.e. if the value is true, add a class.

```
// parse JSON data
var obj = JSON.parse($("#add_form script[type='application/JSON']").html());

$(".size_options li").each() {
    some code
});
```

I'd appreciate any help here.

Comment: You'll need some way to get the id from the li element.  Would that be possible?

Comment: You'll need a way to match up each `product_options` element with each `.size_options li` element and use `.addClass(...)`

Comment: http://www.dynatable.com/

Comment: In a task like this I would use [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/), it simplify many things when working with JSON and manipulating the DOM

Answer (score 1):

In this case `number of` `li` and `length` of `obj.product_options` should be equal.

```
$(".size_options li").each(function (index) {
    if (obj.product_options[index].in_stock) {
        $(this).addClass("classToBeAdd");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a data-attribute as 'data-can_order' with the same JSON value, then iterate the element and according to the True value append a class.

But i will suggest prior to check the 'in_stock' attribute  with the 'can_order', then append the class.